# How to call the PUT method from a client Java?

Tags: java, rest, put, jersey-client

I have the method below:

```
@PUT
@Path("/reduceEnergy/{id}/{action}")
String reduceEnergyConsumption(@PathParam("id") int id, 
                               @PathParam("action") String action);
```

I want to call this method from a client. (In case, when I have a GET Method, I wrote like that:

```
String response = target.path("air_quality")
                        .path("reduceEnergy/"+action)
                        .request()
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                        .get(String.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

But now I have a PUT method. I wrote like that:

But I don't know how to complete it or to correct it

```
Response response = target.path("aqsensor")
                          .path("reduceEnergy/"+pr+"/"+action)
                          .request()
                          .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                          .put(null);
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```

Thanks for helping me find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send `null` in the put, you need to send an [Entity](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html)

Given the following definition of the endpoint:

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @PUT
    @Path("/reduceEnergy/{id}/{action}")
    public String reduceEnergyConsumption(@PathParam("id") int id, 
                                          @PathParam("action") String action) {
        System.out.println("id: " + id);
        System.out.println("action: " + action);
        return "";
    }
}
```

You can do it like this:

```
Entity<String> userEntity = Entity.entity("", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

Response response = target.path("myresource/reduceEnergy/10/action")
                          .request()
                          .put(userEntity);

System.out.println("Status: " + response.getStatus());
```

This oputputs:

```
id: 10
action: action
Status: 200
```